# Add a right sided border to a column in a list in SharePoint

Tags: column, json, formatting

I'm hoping to add a plain black border to break up the columns on what is going to be a list with a lot of columns.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use following JSON column formatting in order to apply border

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "sp-field-borderRightRegular sp-field-borderRightSolid"
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

You can also use other border class like **sp-field-borderLeftRegular** and **sp-field-borderLeftSolid**

You need to apply column formatting to all the columns where you need border and make sure that in case of special field like Lookup, Managed Metadata, Image you need to handle rendering separating. Currently in above JSON,I have used **@currentField** which will work fine for normal text, number fields.

In my case it looks like as below
[image]

I couldn't find those class names in [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#style), I found it from [here](https://zerg00s.github.io/sp-modern-classes/).